# Unix command to append a space to all files in directory (recursive)

Tags: bash, unix

Hi guys I need to append a space character to the end of all files in all subdirectories. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i '${s/$/ /}' {} \;
```